# I can't compile SDL_net in MinGW

Tags: c, mingw, dosbox

Every time i try to compile SDL_net it says

`SDLnet.c: In function 'SDLNet_GetLocalAddresses':
SDLnet.c:215:69: error: 'ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW' undeclared (first use in this function)
     if ((dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen)) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
SDLnet.c:215:69: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
SDLnet.c:223:21: error: 'NO_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (dwRetVal == NO_ERROR) {
                     ^~~~~~~~
make: *** [SDLnet.lo] Error 1`

Comment: Please clear your question bit more

Comment: I am compiling DOSBox in Mingw by tutorial in official wiki. Installed MinGW, compiled and installed sdl1.2, then by trying to compile sdl_net it errors out.

Comment: Isn't there a precompiled sdl_net for mingw?

Comment: I see precompiled for VC

Answer (score 0):

https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=55706#p609435
Use my Mingw guide, it's in the Google Drive link

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer will be more useful to users more quickly if you include the relevant content from the link in your answer and your answer will remain useful if the link goes away. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer